# How to limited producer and read messages by consumers?

Tags: go, shutdown

I want get application producer-consumer(with shutdown by signals) with Go.

A producer constantly generate messages in a queue with a limit of 10.
Some consumers read and process this channel.
If the number of messages in the queue is 0, the producer again generates 10 messages.
When a stop signal is received, the producer stops generating new messages, and the consumers process everything that is in the channel.

I found a code, but can't understand if it works correctly because found strange things:

1. Why, after stopping the program, not all messages from the queue were processed, it seems that part of the data was lost. (in the screenshot, 15 messages were sent, but 5 were processed)
2. How to correctly limit the queue to a limit of 10 messages, that is, we must write 10 messages, wait for processing when the counter of queue becomes 0 and write 10 again?
3. Is it possible inform the producer after stop signal so that he no longer generates new messages to the channel? (In the screenshot, the producer managed to write to the queue - 12,13,14,15)

Result:

[image]

Code example:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    const nConsumers = 2

    in := make(chan int, 10)
    p := Producer{&in}
    c := Consumer{&in, make(chan int, nConsumers)}
    go p.Produce()
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go c.Consume(ctx)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(nConsumers)
    for i := 1; i <= nConsumers; i++ {
        go c.Work(wg, i)
    }
    termChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(termChan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-termChan

    cancelFunc()
    wg.Wait()
}

type Consumer struct {
    in   *chan int
    jobs chan int
}

func (c Consumer) Work(wg *sync.WaitGroup, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for job := range c.jobs {
        fmt.Printf("Worker #%d start job %d\n", i, job)
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(3000+rand.Intn(3000)))
        fmt.Printf("Worker #%d finish job %d\n", i, job)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Worker #%d interrupted\n", i)
}

func (c Consumer) Consume(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        select {
        case job := <-*c.in:
            c.jobs <- job
        case <-ctx.Done():
            close(c.jobs)
            fmt.Println("Consumer close channel")
            return
        }
    }
}

type Producer struct {
    in *chan int
}

func (p Producer) Produce() {
    task := 1
    for {
        *p.in <- task
        fmt.Printf("Send value %d\n", task)
        task++
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why, after stopping the program, not all messages from the queue were processed, it seems that part of the data was lost.

That's because when the `ctx` is done, `(Consumer).Consume` stops reading from the `in` channel, but the goroutine created by `go p.Produce()` still writes to the `in` channel.

The demo below fixes this issue and simplify the source code.

**Notes**:

1. `Produce` stops when the `ctx` is done. And it closes the `in` channel.
2. The field `jobs` is removed from the `Consumer` and the workers read from the `in` channel directly.
3. The following requirement is ignored because it's weird. A common behavior is when a job is produced, and the `in` channel is not full, the job will be sent to the `in` channel immediately; when it's full, the send operation will block until a job is read from the `in` channel.

   > If the number of messages in the queue is 0, the producer again generates 10 messages

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    const nConsumers = 2

    ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    defer stop()

    in := make(chan int, 10)
    p := Producer{in}
    c := Consumer{in}
    go p.Produce(ctx)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(nConsumers)
    for i := 1; i <= nConsumers; i++ {
        go c.Work(&wg, i)
    }

    <-ctx.Done()
    fmt.Printf("\nGot end signal, waiting for %d jobs to finish\n", len(in))
    wg.Wait()
}

type Consumer struct {
    in chan int
}

func (c *Consumer) Work(wg *sync.WaitGroup, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for job := range c.in {
        fmt.Printf("Worker #%d start job %d\n", i, job)
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(3000+rand.Intn(3000)))
        fmt.Printf("Worker #%d finish job %d\n", i, job)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Worker #%d interrupted\n", i)
}

type Producer struct {
    in chan int
}

func (p *Producer) Produce(ctx context.Context) {
    task := 1
    for {
        select {
        case p.in <- task:
            fmt.Printf("Send value %d\n", task)
            task++
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
        case <-ctx.Done():
            close(p.in)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx, it solved my problems. I got what i want like https://i.postimg.cc/gjVwPJ2h/QOViaup-Ydf.png